# PHP sending form data to the database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

On my index page, I have registration forms (first name, last name etc.). On my registration page i have the same forms with the same names.

The problem I am having is when i fill out the form and press submit the data doesnt end up in the database.

I have (in the form tag)form `method="POST"`

What should `Action` be equal to?

I have read that it should equal the registration page. Is this true and if so what php code should be on top of this page ?

Currently, I have: `include('connection.php');`on top of both the `index.php` and `registration.php`, however when I press submit the data isn't displayed in the database.

**code_exec.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$email1=$_POST['email1'];
$email2=$_POST['email2'];
$pass1=$_POST['pass1'];
$pass2=$_POST['pass2'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'Users'(fname, lname, email1, email2, pass1, pass2) VALUES('$fname', $lname', '$email1', '$email2', '$pass1', '$pass2')");
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "mysql5.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a1231901_Members";
$mysql_user = "a1231901_Admin";
$mysql_password = "pass";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect to database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not find database");
?>
```

Anything else needed ?

Comment: please share your code,and i think  that u are expecting the form data to be inserted without any insert query ?

Comment: You are very confused Paul. Submitting the form has nothing to do with the database.

Comment: You need to have a DBC of some sort - like `mysqli` (if using mysql). The action needs to be the php where you have the database connection.

Comment: Your best bet is to post up your php code so that people can analyze it.  And based off the description you provide, listing any errors you see when the code is executed, along with any changes to the code you have tried to show you have made an effort, then the community can step in to try to help you.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Well it does in a small sense in that the OP needs to make sure the form has been submitted before trying to insert into the DB, or his next question will be "What are all these undefined index errors about?" ;)

Comment: Why do your users have two passwords and two emails?

Comment: @Jessica: Registration form perhaps? Verification checks?  Dont' need to be in the database twice though.

Comment: @SlyRaskal That was my point, why would you put that stuff in the database twice? They're supposed to be the same in that case, and then you have two columns with the exact same data.

Comment: @Jessica: Agreed.  not to mention that he's also using mysql_* functions that are deprecated.

Comment: @Jessica so you can verify the email and password

Comment: From what i understand when data is inputted into a form and the user clicks submit, that data is passed to another php page which then inserts that data into the database ?

Comment: Paul have a look to my answer and then follow the link

Comment: Paul, this is in response to your response to @Jessica, if you wish to verify the users email and password, that's great, but there is not need to store it in the database twice.  You verify it upon form submission, not database insertion.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you should start from the beginnig studing PHP, HTML and SQL.

The `action` in the html form indicate where the script should send the data after the submission. You have to create a `php script` that grab that data from `POST` and save them to the database using `SQL`. **Php will not do that for you automatically**.

Second is not a good idea have two different pages with the same data, if you will change one you shoul remember to edit also the other form, so the best thing is create a file just for the form and then include it.

Have a look at **[this link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-a-sign-up-form-registration-with-php-and-mysql/28675)** to *understand* how to create a form and save data into the database: